# c and c++ linkage with libraries

Tags: c++, c, extern, linkage

Suppose I have a C++ library lib.h that uses classes and templates. Suppose also that I have a custom C++ header myLink.h with the following:

```
#include "lib.h"

  //call methods from lib.h that use templates and classes
  //  and return an integer based off of the information gained from calling functions lib.h  
  extern "C" int foo(int param1, const int param2);
```

Now suppose I am in a C file called test.c. Is it legal to call function foo() as follows?

```
//in test.c
int first = foo(5, 6);
```

Also, what is going on at the object code / linker phase of compilation?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to make your "myLink.h" capable of compiling from both C and C++, e.g. by using `#ifdef __cplusplus` to wrap `extern "C" {` and `}` on separate lines.  That way the `int foo(int param1, const int param2);` part would be visible to plain C code, and the rest would be visible to C++.  Without this, your "test.c" would need a separate way to declare the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it legal to call function foo() as follows?

```
 int first = foo(5, 6);
```

Yes, it's legal.  Although you should read below to make sure this legal call will link.

> what is going on at the object code / linker phase of compilation?

The use of classes won't interfere.  C++ classes will be compiled to object code that the linker will understand.

**Edit from Chris Dodd's comment:**

Your templates will also be created by virtue of `foo` calling them.

Comment: Not really true -- if `foo` uses any templates, they'll be instantiated when you compile the C++ source file that defines `foo`.

Comment: You probably need to link with a C++-aware linker.  The C++ side may have code that accesses static objects, uses exception handling, or any number of other things that require C++-specific initialization code.